# CustomListViewAdapter misbehaves when using if/switch statement in getView() method

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

i am working on this android application with ListView. i created a custom adapter for that,and what i am trying to do is setting onClickListener for a TextView in the first row of the list view (item 0 of the list). Only this item's TextView should have a listener. But when i put an if or a switch statement things get out of hand and the row at position 0 shares this position with row at position 2 so the textview in second row also gets a listener.I have 4 rows so after that the rows become 0,1,2 instead of 0,1,2,3 .Any idea what could be causing this?

```
  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


      ViewHolder holder=null;

      LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      if(convertView==null)
      {
          holder = new ViewHolder();

          convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, null);

          holder.imageViewPhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
          holder.textViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.namemain);
          holder.textViewProfession= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profession);
          holder.textViewNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
          holder.imageViewFacebook = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.facebook);
          holder.imageViewTwitter = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.twitter);
          holder.imageViewGoogle= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.google);

          convertView.setTag(holder);
      }
      else{
          holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
          Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, (position > lastPosition) ? 100 : -200, 0);
          animation.setDuration(400);
          convertView.startAnimation(animation);
      }

      Contact aContact = (Contact) getItem(position);

      holder.textViewName.setText(aContact.getName());
      holder.imageViewPhoto.setImageResource(aContact.getImageNumber());
      holder.textViewProfession.setText(aContact.getProfession());
      holder.textViewNumber.setText(aContact.getCellNumber());
      holder.imageViewFacebook.setImageResource(aContact.getImageFb());     
      holder.imageViewTwitter.setImageResource(aContact.getImageTwt());
      holder.imageViewGoogle.setImageResource(aContact.getImageGoo());


      if(position==0){

              holder.textViewProfession.setGravity(0x11);

              holder.textViewProfession.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {

                      Log.i("row"+getItemId(position)," "+position);


                  }
              });

      }


      lastPosition = position;

      return convertView;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(position==0){

              holder.textViewProfession.setGravity(0x11);

              holder.textViewProfession.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {

                      Log.i("row"+getItemId(position)," "+position);


                  }
              });

      }
else{
              holder.textViewProfession.setGravity(0x11);

              holder.textViewProfession.setOnClickListener(null);
}
```

If you use viewHolder then its compulsory to write two cases if and else for the textview to handle properly ... Try this it will work only for Zeroth item...

Comment: Thanks alot man it worked. I was not aware both cases needed to be covered for this to be handled properly